# Font creation with canvas for widths over 8px

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am using a canvas element to draw pixel based letters so that I can export them as sets of HEX values. This font will be used on certain monitors, so the accuracy is necessary. My code produces an array of DEC values that are later translated to HEX values.

On canvases the width of which does not exceed 8px, the produced DEC values match the values I was given for pixel characters.

On canvases the width of which exceeds 8px, I was told that I need to add a new byte for every row of pixels.

The loop I am using to produce the DEC values:

```
for (let x = 0; x < actualWidth; x++) {
  let col = 0;
  let bit = 0;

  for (let y = actualHeight - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
    const tempData = tempContext.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    const r = tempData[0];
    const g = tempData[1];
    const b = tempData[2];
    const a = tempData[3];
    const isOn = r === 0 && g === 0 && b === 0 && a === 255;

    col = (col << 1) | (isOn ? 1 : 0);
    bit++;

    if (bit === 8 || (y === 0 && bit > 0)) {
      pxlArray.push(col);
      col = 0;
      bit = 0;
    }
  }
}

console.log(pxlArray);
```

I started drawing on a 5x7 canvas to check the DEC values against the given file. The pattern I drew for the letter A is:

```
00100
01010
10001
10001
11111
10001
10001
```

where 1s are active pixels and 0s are empty pixels, produces the following correct DEC values: `[124, 18, 17, 18, 124]`. The correct output carried on for the rest of the alphabet.

I started drawing on a 10x14 canvas, where the following pattern for the letter A:

```
0001111000
0001111000
0001111000
0011001100
0011001100
0011001100
0110000110
0110000110
0111111110
0111111110
0110000110
1110000111
1100000011
1100000011
```

should produce the following array of DEC values: `[0, 56, 192, 63, 248, 15, 62, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 62, 3, 248, 15, 192, 63, 0, 56]`, but it does not. Instead, the pattern I have to draw to get the same array of DEC values is the following:

```
0111111110
0111111110
0110000110
1110000111
1100000011
1100000011
0001111000
0001111000
0001111000
0011001100
0011001100
0011001100
0110000110
0110000110
```

It is visible that almost the bottom half of the letter A needs to be drawn on the top half of the canvas, whereas the top half of the letter A needs to be drawn on the bottom half of the canvas, which is wrong.

How could I approach this, so that my regular drawing of the letter A, without its halves being reversed, produces the desired array of DEC values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It renders by the column, pushing every byte (8 bits). Therefore
your inner loop should go from `0` to `innerHeight - 1`.

```js
const arr = [
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
]
const actualWidth = arr[0].length;
const actualHeight = arr.length;
const pxlArray = []

for (let x = 0; x < actualWidth; x++) {
  var exp = 0;
  var byte = 0;
  var byteSize = 8;

  for (let y = 0; y < actualHeight; y++) {
    // console.log(x,y)
    /*
    const tempData = tempContext.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    const r = tempData[0];
    const g = tempData[1];
    const b = tempData[2];
    const a = tempData[3];
    const isOn = r === 0 && g === 0 && b === 0 && a === 255;
    */
    const isOn = arr[y][x]
    var bit = isOn ? 1 : 0;
    byte += bit * Math.pow(2, exp++)

    if (exp == byteSize || y == actualHeight - 1) {
      pxlArray.push(byte);
      byte = 0;
      exp = 0;
    }

  }
}

console.log(pxlArray);
```

Comment: Using the commented implementation for the `isOn` produced the correct result of DEC values. I see what I was missing now. I really appreciate your assistance.